# how to remove default subject value "Call" from log a call button from activity history?

Tags: standard-objects, configuration, button, default-value, standard-field

I want to remove the default subject value "Call" from the 'log a call' page from activity history section on case page. Could it be possible?
Thank you.

[image]

Thanks,
Anitha

Answer (score 0):

In the Task recordtype (if you have any recordtype), choose Subject field and remove `Call` from Selected Values as follows:

[image: Task Subject]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this functionaliy in classic, then you can create new List button by using url hack. We can set the subject to blank by using following steps - 
When click on log a call button -> url would be like below if I clicked from Contact record -

```
baseURL/00T/e?title=Call&who_id=0036F000032eoFm&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=%2F0036F000032eoFm
```

So Just create new button and set blank value to tsk5 attribute in url.
Go to Buttons, Links, and Actions of Task - > New Button or Link - > Select List Button as radio type ->

```
baseUrl+'00T/e?title=Call&who_id='+parentRecordId+'&followup=1&tsk5=&retURL=%2F+ParentRecordId'
```