# How to remove default picklist value in the Task Subject field on my Global Action

Tags: global-actions, default-value

When going to an Account record and using the "Log A Call" Global action, the Subject has a default of "Call" showing on the screen.
I ensured the following:

- The Global Action does NOT have a predefined value set for Subject
- The Subject field does NOT have a picklist value flagged as Default
- The record Type assigned to the Global Action does NOT have a value flagged as default

I'm trying to figure out what is setting this default still.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's controlled by the Activity (Task or Event) record type. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253837/how-to-remove-default-subject-value-call-from-log-a-call-button-from-activity

Comment: @identigral: I am confused by the link you shared...that suggests removing the Call value from the available options, NOT just as the default value. I dont want to remove it as an option, I just dont want it to be the default value.

Comment: The link was to show you the direction. Better link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral That is one of the bullet items I said already checked..that the Record Type used in the global action does NOT have a default value set for the Subject field